# I'm unable to use my secure domain for checkout in Magento 2.1.5 . Cart shows as empty

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, multistore, shopping-cart

I have one domain with an SSL certificate (storewebsite.com)

I also have little individual sites for different clients.

- teamname.storewebsite.com
- schoolname.storewebsite.com
- organization.storewebsite.com

In Magento 1.9 all I needed to do was go into the web settings and set

> Base_url : http://teamname.storewebsite.com
>
> Secure_base_url : https://storewebsite.com
>
> Use SID on storefront : yes

These settings allowed my customers to shop on their own personal site and then go through checkout on the main domain with an encrypted SSL connection.

**Problem :** In Magento 2.1.5 when I try to go to checkout and get redirected to the main domain the cart is empty. I can go back to the subdomain and the items show back up.

**Question:** Does anyone know how I can get my items to keep on existing when going to checkout on the secure domain?

Comment: do you have redirect enabled?  also cookie name different

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a cookie issue. You are using a subdomain for part of the store and cookies set by https connection in magento by default have Secure flag which means they are not shared with http traffic. If adding to cart happens on secure traffic you get a new session id with secure flag. But you have one already from unsecure traffic. Those 2 cookies are sent in secure checkout and most probably incorrect one is used by magento to initialize session. The best solution is simply to add certificates for all subdomains.